# Is there any way to scroll react navigation tabNavigator header?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

Want to scroll tab navigator header options left and right. Only want to scroll the options not the component. Is there any way?

```js
const MyNav = TabNavigator({
  News: { screen: NewsScreen },
  Videos: { screen: VideosScreen },
  Bands: { screen: BandsScreen },
  Jokes: { screen: JokesScreen },
}, {
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
  animationEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to taBarOptions

```
scrollEnabled: true
```